# How to find all the Trusted entities for the particular role using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

My Code

---

```
def getTrustedEntity(rolename):
 response = iam_client.get_role(RoleName=rolename)
 return response["Role"]["AssumeRolePolicyDocument"]["Statement"]
```

its not getting proper arn of Trusted entities....

Comment: Please share the error as well

Comment: any approach are welcome.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a sample Trust Policy, and what you mean by the "proper ARN of the Trusted entities" that you wish to obtain.

Comment: arn:aws:iam::******:saml-provider/abc.com,
arn:aws:iam::*****:saml-provider/iam.bcd.com,
arn:aws:iam::*******:role/cde-analytics-prod-jenkins-role,

Comment: output look like as below:-                                                         
                            1. arn:aws:iam::******:saml-provider/abc.com,   
                            2. arn:aws:iam::*****:saml-provider/iam.bcd.com, 
                            3. arn:aws:iam::*******:role/cde-analytics-prod-jenkins-role,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return response["Role"]["AssumeRolePolicyDocument"]["Statement"][0]["Principal"]["AWS"]
```

Comment: Please, use ctr+k for change format of your response to a coding format.